# Why rarun2 is not behave like it is described?

Tags: radare2

colleagues.

Simplest question. As many articles in the Net (example https://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/rarun2/) and here on forum are describing, i have a rarun2 profile named "r2_profile" file as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/rarun2
stdin=./debruijn
program=./vuln
```

debruijn is a 100 chars long debruijn sequence.
vuln is a ret2win file from here [The most basic binexp challenge](https://ir0nstone.gitbook.io/notes/types/stack/ret2win)

Next i run

```
r2 -d ./vuln -r r2_profile
```

r2 shell appears whith ./vuln  code stopped. I issue "dc" to continue and gets() waiting for my input instead of automatically eat contents of the files i have configured in profile. What i am doing wrong?